# Mitigating Resize of FullCalendar in List View

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular7, fullcalendar-4

I'm using FullCalendar Angular 7 version and trying to stop the resizing that happens automatically when the "List" button is clicked. The header of the calendar becomes substantially crowded and the title and buttons are almost on top of each other. Also I am using this in creative Tim's Paper Dashboard Pro which had its own V3 implementation of fullCalendar through which I removed most of the sass code except for the custom sass code below to make the header responsive on mobile.

Calendar dimensions are 1105 X 705.02
[image: Header in regular calendar view]
Notice how close everything in the header is. On the FC home page the calendar dimensions do not change
Calendar Dimensions here are 618.36 x 1055.82
[image: Header when in list view]
[image: Result of custom code for mobile]
Mobile Version looks fine
[image: Mobile version looks fine]

html

```
<div class="row">
<full-calendar #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth"  (windowResize)='windowResize($event)' height="auto" style="background: white; padding: 5px" timeZone="UTC"
                (eventClick)="openTaskView($event)" (dateClick)="openDateView($event)" eventLimit='true' aspectRatio="1.8"
                [customButtons]="options.customButtons" [header]="header"  [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [events]="selectedEvents" (eventRender)="calendarEventRender($event)" [selectable]="true"
            </full-calendar>
</div>
```

calendar.ts

```
...
import { Calendar } from "@fullcalendar/core";
import { formatDate } from "@fullcalendar/core";
import { FullCalendarComponent } from "@fullcalendar/angular";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin, {
    ThirdPartyDraggable
} from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import bootstrapPlugin from "@fullcalendar/bootstrap";
import commonPlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-common";
import timegridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid";
import dayGridResourcePlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid";
import timelinePlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline";
import rrulePlugin from "@fullcalendar/rrule";
import momentPlugin from "@fullcalendar/moment";
import timezonePlugin from "@fullcalendar/moment-timezone";
import googlePlugin from "@fullcalendar/google-calendar";
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
...

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
    // Calendar Plugins
    calendarPlugins = [
        dayGridPlugin,
        dayGridResourcePlugin,
        interactionPlugin,
        bootstrapPlugin,
        commonPlugin,
        timegridPlugin,
        timelinePlugin,
        rrulePlugin,
        momentPlugin,
        timezonePlugin,
        googlePlugin,
        listPlugin
    ]; // important!
    header = {
        left: "prev, next today",
        right: "filter,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek",
        center: "title"
    };
...
```

scss custom code

```
.nb-theme-default .btn {
    padding: 5px 1.5rem !important;
}

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .fc-toolbar {
        display: block !important;
        // white-space: nowrap;
        // overflow: hidden;
    }

    .fc-toolbar > div.fc-left,
    .fc-toolbar > div.fc-center,
    .fc-toolbar > div.fc-right {
        float: none !important;
        display: inline-block !important;

    }

    .fc-toolbar > div.fc-center > button {
        padding: 5px 5px !important;
    }

    .fc-toolbar > * > :not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar > div.fc-center > button:nth-child(2) {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar > div.fc-center > h2 {
        margin-right: 5px !important;
    }
}
```

scss import file

```
/*!

 =========================================================
 * Paper Dashboard Pro Angular - v1.1.0
 =========================================================

 * Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-dashboard-pro-angular
 * Copyright 2018 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)

 =========================================================

 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 */
@import "~ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal.scss";
@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";
@import "~angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css";
@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/list/main.css';
// @import '~@fullcalendar/angular/main.css';
// @import '~@fullcalendar/interaction/main.css';
// body.dialog-open {
//   //max-width:100%;
//   //overflow: scroll;
// }
// .cal-day-column {
//   //width:71;
// }
// .cal-header {
//   //width:71;
// }
// .nsm-dialog {
//   //min-width:100%;
// }
@media screen and (min-width: 991px){
  .nsm-dialog {
    min-width:100%;
  }
}
.nsm-body {
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
// .isSelected {
//   background-color: lightblue !important;
// }
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'paper-dashboard/variables';
@import 'paper-dashboard/mixins';

// Plugins CSS
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-bootstrap-switch';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-bootstrap-table';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-nouislider';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-animate-bootstrap-notify';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-perfect-scrollbar';

@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-card-wizard';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-datetimepicker';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-bootstrap-select';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-jasny-fileupload';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-tagsinput';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-datatables.net';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-jquery.jvectormap';
@import 'paper-dashboard/plugins/plugin-fullcalendar';


// Core CSS
@import 'paper-dashboard/nucleo-outline';
@import 'paper-dashboard/nucleo';
@import 'paper-dashboard/buttons';
@import 'paper-dashboard/social-buttons';
@import 'paper-dashboard/animated-buttons';
@import 'paper-dashboard/inputs';
@import 'paper-dashboard/typography';
@import 'paper-dashboard/misc';
@import 'paper-dashboard/misc-extend';
@import 'paper-dashboard/navbar';
@import 'paper-dashboard/dropdown';
@import 'paper-dashboard/alerts';
@import 'paper-dashboard/images';
@import 'paper-dashboard/tables';
@import 'paper-dashboard/footers';
@import 'paper-dashboard/fixed-plugin';

// components
@import 'paper-dashboard/checkboxes-radio';
@import 'paper-dashboard/progress';
@import 'paper-dashboard/badges';
@import 'paper-dashboard/pagination';
@import 'paper-dashboard/info-areas';
@import 'paper-dashboard/pills';
@import 'paper-dashboard/tabs';
@import 'paper-dashboard/popups';
@import 'paper-dashboard/modals';
@import 'paper-dashboard/carousel';
@import 'paper-dashboard/sidebar-and-main-panel';
@import 'paper-dashboard/timeline';



// cards
@import 'paper-dashboard/cards';
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-chart";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-map";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-user";

@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-background";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-collapse";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-contributions";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-info-area";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-lock";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-pricing";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-profile";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-signup";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-stats-mini";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-stats";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-subcategories";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-testimonials";
@import "paper-dashboard/cards/card-tasks";



// example pages and sections
@import 'paper-dashboard/example-pages';
@import 'paper-dashboard/sections';


@import 'paper-dashboard/responsive';
@import 'paper-dashboard/media-queries';
```

Comment: Please show your calendar code and also a screenshot of the issue, thanks. Also if you have any custom CSS of your own in the same page please remove it, and then test again to see if you still have the same issue

Comment: P.S. you've tagged this as fullCalendar version 4 but then posted the stylesheet for version 3.1. please clarify exactly which version you are using. Or maybe that's the cause of your problem, maybe you are using the wrong stylesheet in your page??

Comment: @ADyson thanks for pointing that out. v4 Styling was being overwritten by that file. Deleted the contents except for the custom code above. I'm 98% sure I'm referencing the correct stylesheet through my imports now

Comment: Ok. You still seem to have some heavily customised CSS. is it a bootstrap theme or something? Again try removing that and running with the basic CSS provided by fullCalendar, and see if you still have the issue. We need to rule out (or in) external influences to see if the issue lies within fullCalendar or elsewhere.

Comment: @ADyson. You were absolutely correct. Lots of CSS and is a bootstrap theme. In the end, just wrapping the calendar in a card solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being related to the html/css that came along with the template.  Almost every component is built within a card. As opposed to pin pointing the exact code that was causing the calendar to resize, simply wrapping fullCalendar in a card fixed the problem perfectly and also added some styling to make it look better.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-user">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <full-calendar #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" 
                            (windowResize)='windowResize($event)'
                            height="auto" 
                            timeZone="UTC" 
                            (eventClick)="openTaskView($event)"
                            (dateClick)="openDateView($event)" 
                            eventLimit='true' 
                            aspectRatio="1.8"
                            [customButtons]="options.customButtons" 
                            [header]="header" 
                            [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
                            [events]="selectedEvents" 
                            (eventRender)="calendarEventRender($event)" 
                            [selectable]="true"
                        </full-calendar>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```